# Trying to get value from drop down several drop downs and then save it to associated post's specified ACF Field

Tags: php, wordpress

I have very basic PHP knowledge and feel I keep going in circles. I need to have the value of the drop down update a posts "did they show up field" with yes or no. (Then based on yes or no do more stuff). However for my question / help seeking, I am looking as to what's the best way to get the field along with the associated post id. I can get one or the other but can't seem to get both at the same time.

Most of the code below is to set up the table. Then the user selects yes / no if the person showed up. Then when a person clicks "Update", take the value and associated it to that post.

Any help would be great!

```
<?php 

$pickUpDate = get_field('pick_up_date', 167);

$messages=array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(empty($value))
        $messages[] = "Hey you forgot to fill this field: $key";
} 
print_r($messages);


$posts_id_num = array(); 


add_action('acf/save_post', 'acf_save_post', 5);

function my_acf_save_post($post_id) {
    
    $get_old_value = get_field('did_they_show_up', $post_id);

    echo $get_old_value . "<br />";

    //update_field('did_they_show_up', $post_id, $value); 

    $loop_counter = 0; 

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        $loop_counter++; 

        echo $key.$loop_counter." keyy <br />"; 

        echo $posts_id_num[$loop_counter];  

        // echo $loop_counter; 

        echo $post_id . " post <br />"; 

        echo $key . " key <br />";
        echo $value . " value <br /><br />"; 
    }

} 


$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'clients',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_query' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'date_of_last_pick_up',
            'compare' => '=',
            'value' => $pickUpDate,
        ),
    ),
    'numberposts' => -1,

);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

?>

<form id="updates" method="post" action=""> 

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th scope="col">Row #</th>
        <th scope="col">Did they arrive</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Pick Up Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Adults</th>
        <th scope="col">Children</th>
        <th scope="col">Dogs</th>
        <th scope="col">Cats</th>
    </thead>

<?php 

$row_num = 1; 



// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $id = get_the_ID(); 

        array_push($posts_id_num, $id);

        // echo $id . "<br />"; 
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php 
                echo $row_num; 
                $row_num ++; 
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select form="updates" class="show-up" name='<?php echo "show-up-" . $row_num ?>' >
                <option value='' disabled selected>---</option>
                <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                <option value="no"> No</option>
            </select>            
        </td>

        <td>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a> 
        
        </td>

        <td> 

            <?php 
                    $nextPickUp = get_field('date_of_last_pick_up'); 
                    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'Ymd', $nextPickUp );

                    if ( $nextPickUp ) {
                        echo $date -> format('M j Y'); 
                    } else {
                        echo '----'; 
                    }
            ?>

        </td>

        <td>
            <?php if (get_field('adults')) {
                the_field('adults');
                } else {
                    echo '----';
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php if (get_field('children')) {
                the_field('children');
                } else {
                    echo '----';
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php if (get_field('dogs')) {
                the_field('dogs');
                } else {
                    echo '----';
                }
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php if (get_field('cats')) {
                the_field('cats');
                } else {
                    echo '----';
                }
            ?>
        </td>

    </tr>

    <?php
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    // no posts found
    ?> <p>No posts found</p> <?php
}
?>

</table>

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Update">

</form>

<?php 

$values_array = array();
            
if( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
    // Do something.

    echo count($posts_id_num) . "<br /><br />";

    // my_acf_save_post($id_num);

    $l = 0; 

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        
        //echo $posts_id_num; 
        echo $l; 
        $l++; 
    }

    // my_acf_save_post($id);

    /*
    foreach ($posts_id_num as $id_num) {

       my_acf_save_post($id_num);
    }
    */ 
        
}
    
?>
```

I have tried a bunch of forwhile loops and trying to echo out a bunch of various things and variables that might help get the specific number of the post and associated in the specific key in the $_POST object.

Comment: Name your select fields `name="show-up[123]"`, with the post id in square brackets - then you will get an array in `$_POST['show-up']`, and the keys of that array will be those post IDs. (And make sure you use the actual post id, not just a loop counter. Post IDs won't always be consecutive, for example if you delete one.)

Comment: That's genius. Thanks!